FX Arbitrage and "modified" Bellman-Ford algorithm
Trying to understand this recent publication: [Y. Zhang et al.] - An Improved Algorithm to Identify More Arbitrage Opportunities on Decentralized Exchanges.
While all the explanations about building the line graph are quite clear. The logic behind the MMBF algorithm is not much developed nor explained.
See Algorithm 1:

While I think I get the part where we're talking about $Dis_{(v_i,v_j)}$ since it's straight up from the original Bellman-Ford algorithm, I have a much harder time with:

$Path_{(v_i,v_j)}$: What is $Path$ in a more specific coding language? A map to a list of pair $(i,j)$? What's its initialization? What does the "$+$" operator in $Path_{(v_j,v_l)}=Path_{(v_i,v_j)}+(v_j,v_l)$ mean?
$t=k_d[-1]$: Since $k_d$ is a pair of int does it mean $k_d[-1]=k_d.second$ in a way?


Are you familiar with the meaning of Dictionary within Python? I think that is probably what they have in mind.
